# Gravity Forms Plugin - Show custom columns for entries in back end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gravity-forms-plugin

[image: Screenshot of image]

In the above image you can see the entries listing of my gravity forms.

I think gravity forms display only first 4 input fields for the form submission in the listing view.

```
'Enter Number'
'Untill 31st July..'
'From 1st Aug..'
'From 7th Nov..'
```

These are the columns being display in the listing view.

But, these columns have no use as they are just information columns
So I want to display different 4 input fields as columns from my form.

Is there a way to do that, or if someone has come across that. Will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Jasdeep

Comment: I assume that little gear sign on the right might help you. Or perhaps 'Screen options` at the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: Thankyou so much mate ... don't know how I skipped that little gear icon.